# Is there a way to detect if a Facebook login to my app came from a Business/Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-rest-api

I have an application with two distinct interfaces. One is aimed to "common" Facebook users, and the other is aimed to "Companies or Pages" from Facebook.

Once someone uses Facebook to login to my app, is there a way to detect if this login came from a Company/Page? If not, is there any way to detect if a user "owns" a page so the application can let they choose the interface they want to use?

Comment: AFAIK only normal users can log into 3rd-party apps anyway. It is not possible to login with a business manager account or something like that.

Comment: _“is there any way to detect if a user "owns" a page”_ – `/me/accounts`